# Почему "затрапезный"?

Tags: фразеология

Подумалось, а почему слово "затрапезный" означает "непрезентабельный", "убогий"? Ведь, по идее, за трапезу, наоборот, надо принаряжаться.

Comment: За трапезой - это *после* трапезы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю, "за трапезой" - это и есть единственная и основная. Разговоры про всяких  купцов - обычная история, как правило ничего общего с фактами не имеющая. 
Более того, даже  если предположить наличие в подобных версиях хоть какое зерно, то сама фамилии становится немотивированной. Скорее уж купца назвали по ткани, не наоборот, такое было широко распространено, отсюда многочисленные "купеческие фамилии": Морковниковы, Крестовские, Пороховщиковы...
А слово "затрапезный" - из монастырского быта. После праздничной трапезы монахи обычно переодевались в повседневное.

28.02
Возникает интересная мысль. А не может ли само слово "затрапезный" первоначально относиться к самому столовому белью?!
При том, что никаких серьёзных данных о том, что оная мануфактура (см. других авторов) была сколько-нибудь значима по этой части, нет.

В отношении затрапезной ткани... Несколько найденных образцов оной ставит под сомнение вообще всю версию о носильной ткани. Это т.н. "скатерная" тнань, похоже на набивной лен. 
http://ru.dreamstime.com/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C-image13929404
Разумеется, это может быть вторичным. Но где тогда образцы исходной?

Comment: Так и звучало бы тогда затрАпезный, а не затрапЕзный.

Comment: >Так и звучало бы тогда затрАпезный, а не затрапЕзный.  

А вот это уже просто бред. Вы бы хоть со словарем ударений сверялись, если уж не знаете.

Comment: "В затрапезах не хожу, и то слава те господи!" - Салтыков-Щедрин, Господа Головлевы. "Женщины, в затрапезах, полосатых платках, с детьми на руках - стояли около крыльца" - Л. Толстой, Детство. "По моему состоянию, я вас могла бы только в ситцевых да в затрапезных платьях водить," - А. Островский, Доходное место.
"Ходил он [Конон] в деревне, по будням, в широком синем затрапезном сюртуке, в серых нанковых штанах и в туфлях на босу ногу," - Салтыков-Щедрин, Пошехонская старина.  
Затрапеза - это разновидность пестряди, по современным меркам - да, для одежды грубовата.

Comment: А трапеза разве была только праздничной?

Answer (score 3):

Был такой купец Иван Максимович Затрапезнов, который в 1722 году получил от Петра I разрешение основать Ярославскую Большую мануфактуру (ныне ОАО Ярославский комбинат технических тканей "Кра́сный Переко́п"). Мануфактура эта занималась производством салфеточного белья, скатертей, полотенец, а кроме того производила дешевую грубоватую льняную или пеньковую ткань, большей частью с синими полосами. Эту ткань, пользующуюся у бедного простого люда большим спросом, в народе прозвали по фамилии купеческой семьи затрапезом, затрапезой, затрапезником. Затрапезный вид, соответственно, имел тот, кто эту дешёвую и некрасивую ткань носил. Ткани правда больше этой не выпускают, а вид остался.

Comment: А фамилия тогда откуда? 
ЗЫ Существование такого купца я не оспариваю. 
Только объём производства и его качество никак не говорит в пользу подобной версии. "Носильное" полотно если и производилось, то в минимальных объёмах. Основной продукцией было столовое бельё, весьма, катати, качественное.

Comment: 1. Xerox тоже в основном не ксероксы производит, но была монополистом в СССР именно в этом сегменте. Мануфактура Затрапезновых в производстве дешевых нательных тканей для населения, тоже долгое время конкурентов имела только в лице кустарей. Соответственно вся городская беднота носила продукцию именно этого предприятия.  
Недостатком монастырской версии является то, что до XVIII века слово "затрапезня" как название ткани нигде не упоминается, в то время как расцвет монастырей пришёлся на более раннюю эпоху.  
Откуда пошла фамилия сказать вряд ли возможно и от ткани лишь один из вариантов.

Comment: Есть фамилия Трапезников. Купеческая фамилия в некоторых источниках приводится - Затрапезников.

Comment: Фамилия есть. И основатель мануфактуры есть. Я, кажется, написал это даже для историков. 
Смысла в том, что фамилия стала названием ткани, не более чем в том, что пиджак называть спинджаком потому, что он на спине висит.

Пассажи насчет Ксероксов - это сразу ффтопку, как не имеющие отношения.

>Мануфактура Затрапезновых в производстве дешевых нательных тканей для населения, тоже долгое время конкурентов имела только в лице кустарей.  

Простите, но я Вам на слово не верю. Источник давайте. 
ЗЫ Фраза насчет того, что это моё дело, верить или нет, источником не является. И желательно - аналоги.

Comment: 4. Например, этот источник, где прямо указывают, что ткань затрапез, изобрёл лично Иван Затрапезников, также указано, что ширпотреб в промышленном масштабе выпускать они начали первыми. http://yarcenter.ru/content/view/33/103/

Comment: 4. http://mirslovarei.com/content_bigbioenc/zatrapeznyj-ivan-maksimovich-156926.html вот ещё ссылка.

Comment: >Например, этот источник,  
  
Вы себя позиционируете как историка. Вам понятие источниковедения, надеюсь, знакомо? Оцените его уровень безымянной статьи в интернете.

ЗЫ Что Вы так упорно пытаетесь сказать ставя единицы перед каждым своим  соообщением?

По поводу ткани - см. мой ответ.

Comment: 7. А где безымянность увидели? Достаточно надёжный сайт и авторская статья видного ярославского историка, председателя Ярославской региональной общественной организации возрождения русской культуры и традиций "Петропавловская слобода" Надежды Балуевой. С исторической точки зрения это конечно не источник, но доступа к ярославским архивам у меня нет.

Answer (score 2):

От ткани "затрапеза" - это не единственная версия. Возможно, оно наложилось на давнее народное, вернее церковное от "за трапезой": затрапезный (разговор, вид)- обиходный, простой, братский. Т.е слишком простой в отличие от праздничного. Такое значение есть у Даля.